# Disabling Dialog Controls MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog

How do  I disable all the controls in a dialog window ? I know I could use 
EnableWindow(FALSE); 
but this doesnt seem like a good idea because now there is no way for the user to click "Ok" or "Cancel" button or press the "X" icon to exit. The dialog is like frozen.

What I am looking for is a way to disable all the controls in a dialog while providing some way for a user to exit.

Another solution is to do it manually by going through all the dialog controls and disabling them but this gets tedious. Any easy way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but going through all of the controls and disabling each of them *is* the easy way.

You can write a general function to do this using [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx) or using a loop calling [GetWindow(... GW_HWNDNEXT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) until it returns NULL for the next window.

Just remember to skip disabling the window that has the IDCANCEL as the id.

Comment: And don't forget: never, ever disable the control which has the focus! If you have to disable that control, first pass the focus on to another control, *then* disable it.